# Different strings used on post revisions and edit pages (please, use existing one)

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, localization, transifex

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9322/revisions

> [image]

Used string `0b0dee08acad5d7c8cbde8ea2de60033`:

> [Edit removed during grace period]

But on edit page used another string (hardcoded?):

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9322/edit/

> [image]

Please, use the same string `0b0dee08acad5d7c8cbde8ea2de60033`.